# Getting exit code from xcopy when it's embedded in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, xcopy

I'm using xcopy this way:

> p = New Process
>
> ```
> psi = p.StartInfo
>
> AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf NetErrorDataHandler
>
> psi.Arguments = "/C "xcopy *SOURCE* *TARGET*"
> psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
> psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
> psi.UseShellExecute = False
> psi.CreateNoWindow = True
> p.Start()        
> p.WaitForExit()
> p.Close()
> ```

It's working. Yet I'm wondering if that's possible to get its exit codes (mentioned [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx)) when it's embedded in cmd.exe? i.e. get the exit codes of **xcopy**

If so - how to?

(if more info is necessary: the "cmd" line above is part of a C# utility.

Comment: How are you calling it? From C# code? Command line? Batch file?

Comment: You don't need to call `cmd` to execute `xcopy`. It is not an internal command and you can call it directly `C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe`

Comment: I actually don't know the command inside the cmd.exe. It could be another commands (I get them as parameters). I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: As stated, you don't really need cmd, you can call xcopy directly with the arguments. You should also be able to get the response from `psi.ExitCode`. As this is more of a C# question, this should be on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)